# Searching values in array of objects /Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider the following arrays of objects :

```
[{ id: 5, name: "Spain"},
 { id: 6, name: "Denmark"},
 { id: 7, name: "USA"},
 { id: 8, name: "Iceland"},
 { id: 9, name: "Greece"},
 { id: 10, name: "UK"},
 { id: 11, name: "Germany"},
 { id: 12, name: "Italy"}]

 [{ id: 13, name: "US"},
 { id: 14, name: "GR"},
 { id: 15, name: "ESP"},
 { id: 16, name: "ICEL"},
 { id: 17, name: "DEN"},
 { id: 18, name: "UK"},
 { id: 19, name: "IT"},
 { id: 20, name: "GER"}]
```

I want to search through the first array and find the respective match for the second array. Or even better get one element from the second array and search for it against all the values in the first array .

- EX. GER = { id: 11, name: "Germany"}
- IT = { id: 12, name: "Italy"}

Is there a best practise for implementing this kind of search ?

Comment: ans how should it get `{ id: 15, name: "ESP"}` by `{ id: 5, name: "Spain"}` ?

Comment: its not clear whats the input and output?

Comment: there is no matching key in either the two arrays. How to there should be a primary key and foreign key relationship between two arrays.

Comment: The problem with this, is that there's nothing to match to programmatically. Conceptually, yes, GER and Germany both represent the same nation, but there's no way for the code to logically match that. You'd be better off adding the abbreviation to the same object that contains the full name. Or if you can't do that for some reason, then add a common "key" that both items share.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest . I want to establish "communication" or mapping between two systems which have different dbs . That's why i have this problem . The program will automatically generate the element from the second array (INPUT) , and i have to map it with an element in the first array (OUTPUT)

Comment: @AlexLemesios It seems like you're in a bad spot. You really should have both pieces of information in a single array of objects. The abbreviation is a perfect key, too. So you could have an array like this:
[{id: 'GER', name: 'Germany'},
...]

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a data structure, you could use an object with the reference to the objects of the first array.

You need to implement it by hand as long as you do not have a relation of the matching `id`.

```
countries = {
    ESP: { id: 5, name: "Spain"},
    DEN: { id: 6, name: "Denmark"},
    US: { id: 7, name: "USA"},
    ICEL: { id: 8, name: "Iceland"},
    GR: { id: 9, name: "Greece"},
    UK: { id: 10, name: "UK"},
    GER: { id: 11, name: "Germany"},
    IT: { id: 12, name: "Italy"}
}
```

Access via

```
countries.ICEL.name // Iceland
```

or

```
country = 'GR'
countries[country].name // Greece
```